# Nested or variable functions of xstring

Tags: macros, strings, xstring

My idea is to use `xstring` package for dealing with some string tests. In my case, I used the `\strLeft` function for extracting the 3 first letters of a string. Then, I use this result in `\IfStrEqCase` function.

```
\newcommand\textttarg[1]{\expandarg #1\,\,  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{{BOV}{bbov}{BOH}{bboh}}[ff]}
\def\nnnnn{\expandarg\StrLeft{BOVComp}{3}}
\nnnnn\\
\textttarg{\nnnnn}
```

The result is very strange because the word is `BOVComp`. Extract the 3 first letters: `BOV`. The test `\IfStrEqCase` don't see the 3 letters correctly and returns the default result `ff`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\textttarg[1]{\expandarg #1\,\,  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{{BOV}{bbov}{BOH}{bboh}}[ff]}
\def\nnnnn{\expandarg\StrLeft{BOVComp}{3}}

\nnnnn\\
\textttarg{\nnnnn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\IfStrEqCase` sees `\expandarg\StrLeft{BOVComp}{3}`, not `BOV`.

Comment: @egreg Are you sure? `#1` returns `BOV` (see https://www.overleaf.com/2122963tfzqky). If yes, do you have any idea for expanding `#1` because the test?

Comment: `\StrLeft` is *not* (fully) expandable. It's the set of instructions for producing the first *n* tokens from its argument, but `\expandarg` doesn't do the business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `\expandarg`, the *first* token in the arguments of `\IfStrEqCase` is expanded *once*.

Since your argument is `\nnnnn`, this results in doing

```
 \IfStrEqCase{\expandarg\StrLeft{BOVComp}{3}}{{BOV}{bbov}{BOH}{bboh}}[ff]
```

so the ‘string’ which is compared against `BOV` or `BOH` is `\expandarg\StrLeft{BOVComp}{3}` and the tests are obviously unsuccessful. Note that when the manual of `xstring` talks about ‘strings’ it actually refers to tokens, because that's what TeX understands.

Using `\fullexpandarg` wouldn't help either, because `\StrLeft` is not fully expandable, since it performs assignments.

Of course, using `\nnnnn` alone prints `BOV`, because in this case TeX goes all the way, performing the necessary assignments.

You probably want

```
\newcommand{\nnnnn}{BOVComp\StrLeft{BOVComp}{3}[\temp]}

\newcommand{\textttarg}[1]{%
  #1
  \begingroup\expandarg % localize the effect of \expandarg
  \IfStrEqCase{\temp}{{BOV}{bbov}{BOH}{bboh}}[ff]%
  \endgroup
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\nnnnn}{BOVComp}

\newcommand{\textttarg}[1]{%
  #1
  \begingroup\expandarg % localize the effect of \expandarg
  \StrLeft{#1}{3}[\temp]%
  \IfStrEqCase{\temp}{{BOV}{bbov}{BOH}{bboh}}[ff]%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\textttarg{\nnnnn}

\textttarg{BOHComp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here's how I'd do it with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\textttarg}{m}
 {
  #1~
  \str_case_x:nnF { \__guuk_get_three:o { #1 } }
   {
    {BOV}{bbov}
    {BOH}{bboh}
   }
   {ff}
}

\cs_new:Npn \__guuk_get_three:n #1
 {
  \__guuk_get_three:w #1 . . . \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__guuk_get_three:n { o }

\cs_new:Npn \__guuk_get_three:w #1 #2 #3 #4 \q_stop
 {
  #1#2#3
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\nnnnn}{BOVComp}

\begin{document}

\textttarg{\nnnnn}

\textttarg{BOHComp}

\textttarg{Uh}

\end{document}
```

[image]